# Export html table with image to an Excel sheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, export-to-excel

I am trying to export html table data to an excel sheet, and I have succeeded in doing it with text and image as well.

```
window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent($('#dvData').html()));
```

But the image is only visible when there is internet available as the image source contains a link.

```
<td><img src="some link" /></td>
```

Is there any way to download the Excel and open it in offline mode to see the image?

Comment: Store the base64-encoded image in localStorage when the page is loaded initially? Then inject that string into the `<img>` tags instead of referencing a URL for the source. That is one of the possibilities, but note that client side storage is often restricted to 5MB per domain.

Comment: You could try base-64 encoding the image and use a data URI: https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/   (but Excel may not support that...)

Comment: @Tim Williams I want to do that for excel itself, because web pages are any how going to be accessible online. But excel will be viewed offline.

Comment: @Terry I tried according to your comment and I did get the image according to data uri in the html page. But I want it to be visible in the excel sheet when the table is exported to excel sheet and the excel sheet is opened offline. Ur comment didn't help in exporting the image to the excel sheet.